# Cross Domain subdomain .post using php

Tags: php, javascript, cross-domain

I have a server with a main domain "maindomain.com" and sub domains. I'll call one "addon.com.

I have an index.php file on the addon.com site that pulls the php files from the root of the maindomain.com folder and it works fine. The problem I'm having is there is a contact form using js Post to a php file called emailform.php and because that file is on the main domain I'm having cross domain issues.

What I did to try and solve the issue was create another php file called subemailform.php in the sub domain folder that only has an include for the emailform.php.

If I go to the subemailform.php page directly the echo in emailform.php shows up. So I know the include is working. But it doesn't send the email out.

I thought this would be a good work around. Any thoughts as to why this won't work and any suggestions?

Partial js code:

```
 function submitEmailForm() {
    $.post('subemailform.php', { domainName: App.get('domainName'), name:     $('#emailFormName').val(), phone: $('#emailFormPhone').val(), skype: $('#emailFormSkype').val(), email: $('#emailFormEmail').val() }, function() {
        // alert('success!');
```

subemailform.php

```
     <?php  
        include 'http://www.maindomain.com/emailform.php';
?>
```

emailform.php has the $name = $_POST['name']; and the mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);  code.

I should point out that the js and the emailform.php work if I call it from the same domain. So I know the code is working.

Comment: A subdomain is "www.example.com" or "fancyname.example.com" when you have a domain "example.com". "addon.com" is not a subdomain to "example.com", it is a completely unrelated domain. Which affects several things in browsers like sharing of cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross domain calls will not work untill you allow as

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST');
```

OR Use JSONP

Comment: Would this still be considered a cross domain call if it's being pulled as an include in php?

Comment: I did understand you question fully but if the call is done through a page rendered from different domain, the yes

Comment: I put this in the htaccess file and it worked: Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"      -- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can user [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) for cross domain ajax requests.
[json-p.org](http://json-p.org/)
[JavaScript Cross-Domain Requests JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510819/1418007)

Answer (score 0):

You can try "P3P" policy.

Visit http://www.w3.org/P3P/